# Intuition for cofibration

Tags: algebraic-topology, intuition

The notion of a fibration has a nice geometric intuition of one topological space (a fiber) being parametrized by another topological space (the base) -- this is taken from the Wikipedia entry on Fibration.

Now, I would like to know if there is an analogous geometric picture for the situation of cofibrations. Like that of a parametrized inclusion of a space into another space (apologies if this is nonsense).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there are precisely the dual diagrams defining a cofibration.  The way to think about them -- the way I think about them, at least -- is just that they're sufficiently nice inclusions, such that the subspace has a bit of "wiggle room".  This is made precise in the definition of a "neighborhood deformation retract (NDR) pair", which you can read about in May's *Concise Course in Algebraic Topology*.  Maybe the best example to keep in mind is when you turn an arbitrary map into a cofibration with the "mapping cylinder" construction; then it's obvious that the subspace has plenty of wiggle room.

Comment: From this perspective, the important aspect of a fibration is not that it has a well-defined fiber (as a homotopy type), but rather that it behaves well with respect to *lifting* maps *through* the morphism.  Dually, the important aspect of a cofibration is that it behaves well with respect to *extending* maps *along* the morphism.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So for cofibration there is not a "dual" geometric intuition to that of the fibration? I mean, I understand the algebraic duality between fibration and cofibration, but cannot grasp the geometric idea (if any) so easily.

Comment: (cont.) An instance of the nice intuition for fibration is for fiber bundles. Here one may have non-trivial bundles, as is always exemplified by the Moebius band. Is there a "dual" geometric picture to this situation? that is, where you define a cofibration "locally" which is nevertheless globally nontrivial?

Comment: @camilo: I'm not sure; there might be some connection that I just don't see though.  However, here is another duality-type statement.  A fibration sits in a fiber sequence, which loops backwards indefinitely (look up the "Puppe sequence", or maybe Dold-Puppe) and induces a lexseq for homotopy classes of maps *in* (e.g. from spheres -- this is the lexseq in homotopy).  On the other hand, a cofibration sits in a cofiber sequence, which suspends forward indefinitely, and this induces a lexseq for homotopy classes of maps *out* (e.g. to Eilenberg-MacLanes -- this is the lexseq in cohomology).

Comment: In this setup, if a fiber sequence $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ is trivial (so $Y \simeq X \times Z$) then the connecting maps in homotopy will be trivial; dually, if a cofiber sequence $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C$ is trivial (so $C \simeq B \vee \Sigma A$) then the connecting maps in cohomology will be trivial.  I think these facts get at what you're asking.

Comment: That's nice, thanks. If you ever come across the geometric situation for nontrivial cofibration, as the example of a Moebius band is for nontrivial fibration, and pay a visit to this question, I will be very grateful!

Comment: I'll let you know if I come across anything, but I think I've read enough at this point that I would've seen something if it existed (beyond what I've already said).  The point of both of these notions -- from a model category point of view, where one converts (up to weak equivalence) any morphism to a fibration or a cofibration willy-nilly -- is that they give us different measurements the "difference" of a morphism, i.e. its failure to be a homotopy equivalence. [cont]

Comment: ... Perhaps the you should read about model categories to see these two notions on a more balanced footing.  Although I will readily admit that this is going in a *less* geometric direction.  Also along the lines of this "difference" perspective is that when you pass to the *stable* homotopy category, these notions of difference become equivalent; indeed, that's kind of the entire point.

Comment: @camilo (I just realized I didn't @ you on the previous comments): Anyways, many maps that you come across will be cofibrations -- for instance, any inclusion of CW-complexes -- and so anytime this induces a nontrivial long exact sequence in cohomology (i.e. it doesn't split into a bunch of short exact sequences, i.e. the connecting homomorphisms aren't all zero), then it must have been a nontrivial cofibration.  The most basic example is perhaps the standard inclusion $S^1 \hookrightarrow D^2$, or even $S^0 \hookrightarrow D^1$ for that matter...

Comment: These two examples are trivial cofibrations right? If yes, what is the simplest example of a nontrivial cofibration?

Comment: No, they are not trivial!  A trivial cofibration is a cofibration which is a weak homotopy equivalence.  Equivalently, the homotopy groups of the cofiber (i.e. the mapping cone) all vanish.

Comment: I just saw this randomly, and noticed that I made a mistake in my previous comment. You can't check weak homotopy equivalences by taking mapping cones; for instance, there are noncontractible ("acyclic") spaces whose suspensions are contractible.